# server client communication using socket in java

Tags: java, client, communication

clientSocket = new Socket(args[0], 4442);
ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(1111);

client sever sockets
full knowlege about

how we decided port no. and socket no.  ???

Answer (score -2):

```
Socket myClient = new Socket(ipAddress, PortNumber);
```

I think this will help you